# Make a Thumbnail Animate In to a Main Container

Tags: jquery

There are no of elements in the container, but there are thumbnails on the side. When you click the thumbnail the corresponding slide should animate to fill the main container.

html:

```
<div id="main_container">
    <div id="img_container">
        <div class="img_main"></div>
        <div class="img_main"></div>
        <div class="img_main"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery :​​​

```
$(".img_main").click(function() {
$(this).css("position",'absolute').transition({
    top: '0px',
});

});​
```

The output is shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BFdNB/1/)

On clicking the grey box it should come out of the bottom container and fill the main container.

I am also using the plugin jquery.transit.

I am trying something similar to this example : http://sokra.github.com/jmpress.js/examples/tab-control/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should just download the source for the plugin you linked to, and use that. It looks good, and is well documented. If you insist on doing it yourself, here is what I would do.

```
<div id="main_container">

</div>

<div id="img_container">

   <div class="img_main">
     <img url="etc" />
   </div>

   <div class="img_main">
     <img src="wherever" />
   </div>

   <div class="img_main">
     <img src="you get the idea" />
   </div>

</div>
```

Then load the image tag in to the html using jquery. Make a CSS class called animate that holds your animation, and then add it to the `img` after loading it into the main div. There are an infinite number of ways to go about this. I suggest you make google your best friend.

jQuery:

```
$(".img_main").click(function() {
    var img = $(this).find('img');
    $('#main_container').html(img.html());
    img.addClass('animate');
  });
});​
```

Or instead you could download the free library at that github page.